# Is there a CMD command to move a file to the next higher folder level?

Tags: cmd

I have something like saved a file here:

C:\Test\test.txt

I now want to move them via CMD so that the path is as follows:

C:\test.txt

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

`move c:\test\test.txt c:\`

The first argument is the source file.

The second argument is the target file or target-directory.

IF you just want to move the file exactly one level up the tree, and you don't know the name of the target directory, then you can use the `..` indicator which means the parent-directory .

example:

`move c:\Test\test.txt   ..`

will move the file into c:\Test .

If any part of the path or filename contains spaces then double-quote the source and/or target name appropriately.

See the help for the move command `help move`.

Comment: The description of `move c:\Test\test.txt   ..` is not correct on current directory is the directory `C:\Test` with the file `test.txt`. The file is moved to ``C:\``, the root directory of drive `C:` and not into `c:\Test` as written as the file is in this directory. Also the command line expects the current directory is the directory containing the file to move.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to move one or more files or folders up one level in folder hierarchy by using `..` as described by Microsoft in the documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file).

The simple approach in a command prompt window would be:

```
for %I in ("C:\test\test.txt") do for %J in ("%~dpI..\") do move "%~I" "%~fJ"
```

The command line in a batch file would be:

```
for %%I in ("%~1") do for %%J in ("%%~dpI..\") do move "%%~I" "%%~fJ"
```

`%~1` references the first argument passed to the batch file which can be a file/directory name without or with a relative or with an absolute path, or even a wildcard pattern to move multiple files/directories up in the directory tree. The files/folders can be passed to the batch file also with a [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) path.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `for /?`
- `move /?`